# Python: add direct to graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I print the graph with

```
data.plot(x='Weight', y='Height', kind='scatter')
```

And it looks

[image: plot]

I need to add to this plot two directs.
I use code

```
w0 = np.linspace(-100, 100, 25)
w1 = np.linspace(-5, 5, 0.25)
data.plot(x='Weight', y='Height', wo, w1, kind='scatter', title=u'Зависимость роста от веса')
```

But it returns error.
I can't find some documentation with it, can you say, what I do wrong?

Data looks like

```
         Height    Weight  weight_cat
Index                                
1      65.78331  112.9925           1
2      71.51521  136.4873           2
3      69.39874  153.0269           3
4      68.21660  142.3354           2
5      67.78781  144.2971           2
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Always post complete error messages. It is also not clear what 'data' is.

Comment: @philippd I've added data to question

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: what is `data`?

Comment: @eyllanesc You can see it in question

Comment: data is a DataFrame?

Comment: Explicit in its variables, matplotlib is independent of pandas, do not assume things. Also so far not responding. **What is the error message?**

Answer (score 1):

You are using pandas to plot your first set of data.
You cannot pass an other set of x,y points to the [`DataFrame.plot()` call](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html?highlight=plot#pandas.DataFrame.plot), you have to do the second plot directly using matplotlib:

```
w0 = np.linspace(-100, 100, 25)
w1 = np.linspace(-5, 5, 0.25)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data.plot(x='Weight', y='Height', kind='scatter', ax=ax)
ax.plot(w0, w1)
```